# get content in div tag in txt file using asp.net help of regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

Text file content div tag multiple times and i want to get content in div tag and display it using regular expression in asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions [shouldn't be used to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If you have XHTML you could use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to achieve this.